# How to set network area dimensions in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I want to set the size of the network area in .ini file, I am using Inet, I want something similar to:

network.field_x = 500
network.field_y = 500

in Castalia.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any [Mobility](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-mobility.html) model in your project and define the physical area using its [parameters](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.mobility.base.MobilityBase.html), for example:

```
**.constraintAreaMinX = 0m
**.constraintAreaMinY = 0m 
**.constraintAreaMaxX = 1000m
**.constraintAreaMaxY = 1000m 
**.constraintAreaMinZ = 0m
**.constraintAreaMaxZ = 0m
```

It should be noticed that one can use Mobility even if nodes do not move - there is [StationaryMobility](https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.mobility.static.StationaryMobility.html).

Comment: (+1) Do you know if these parameters are used for anything else other than mobility? For example, does position of a node inform wireless "link" properties?

Comment: Yes, the position from mobility is taken into all radio propagation/transmission calculations. For example take a look at: `src/inet/physicallayer/ieee80211/bitlevel/Ieee80211LayeredOfdmTransmitter.cc` from INET. There is a lot of `getCurrentPosition()` from mobility instance.

Answer (score 0):

These parameters in Castalia describe the **physical** size of the area where the sensor nodes are deployed. It makes sense to have these parameters **for a sensor network** but not necessarily for an abstract network.

OMNeT++ does not have these kind of parameters. What would be the purpose of them?
I am not sure about INET, but if I had to guess I'd say there are no parameters describing the physical size of the network.

Update: These parameters do exist in INET (see Jerzy D's answer), but since you commented you want to simulate a sensor network, I suggest you review if the models of INET fit your purposes. I don't know of recent developments with INET but I remember in the past INET was not suitable for **my** sensor network simulation needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am simulating a sensor network using INET, that's why I want to set the physical size of the area where my sensor nodes are deployed.

Comment: Maybe INET is not the best framework to use then. Or you have to work with its constraints.